# can not find site by C# code or powershell

Tags: 2013

I am trying to get a spweb (site) and go through its sub sites. when I use powershell get-spweb it says `Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url : http://mysitehost/personal/username and site Url http://mysitehost.` However I can browse to the url and everything is ok.

I searched and find some posts talking about granting rights on the content database. but I have checked and I have already grant rights on the content db.

Comment: Are you certain the user account that you're running the PowerShell and C# code has access to the site as well as the content database? Try running the Powershell window 'As Administrator' first, also.

Comment: Also, ensure you are granting access to the content database using the proper Powershell command : GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("DOMAIN\username")